# Databases transferred with Docker Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, digital-ocean

I have a docker container and image that are running on a local server and public server through digital ocean (same question for a AWS server). If the running image on the digital ocean server creates a database, is it linked to the image so that if i update the image, the intial data is lost? or is databases not linked to docker images so that if i update the docker image, none of the data in the database is lost? can anyone help me figure this out. I can't fund anything online that answers my question.

Comment: Are the DB files in a volume or just in the local file system of your container?

Answer (score 0):

Mount your database docker containers with mount points at host level. By default, docker stores data inside container volume. If your DB data path, inside Dockerfile, is mounted on any volume then your data will not be lost and you can mount every new docker image on the same path. For more details read docker mount points.